# Graphicx Displays File Path, not Image

Tags: graphics

I am using the bmcart.cls file, as it is required for submission to a particular journal (associated with BioMed Central). Using this format, none of the images to which I refer in my code render in the .pdf output; however, the compiler (ShareLaTeX) throws no errors. The code works in the article and nwc document class.

Below is a minimum working example. The graphicx package is loaded in the document preamble. Help?

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]  
    \centering  
    \includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{./figs/WestCoastPowerGrid.pdf}  
    \includegraphics[width=.48\textwidth]{./figs/WestCoastPowerGrid2.pdf}  
    \caption{The  West Coast Power Grid introductory slide and degree distribution slide (by Ben McCaleb)}  
    \label{fig:WestCoastPowerGrid}  
\end{figure}
```

Thank you,
Jon

Comment: you have `draft` specified as a documentclass or package option

Comment: note a "minimal working example" should be something people can run to see the issue, so should have `\documentclass`... `\end{document}` and use a generally available image such as `example-image`

Comment: (@DavidCarlisle but mainly @ JonR) I wonder if the class is to blame (i.e. maybe it loads `[draft]{graphicx}` for reasons that make sense to the journal. I've seen similar things before when figures are expected separately.

Comment: Thank you for your help, gentlemen. It does indeed seem as though the journal expects the figures and illustrations separately and structured their class file to make that work. I was swimming against the stream. No longer. I'll raft with the current.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`bmcart` class](http://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/tex) comes with a template file that includes the comment:

> All additional figures and files should be attached separately and not
>   embedded in the \TeX\ document itself.

and also:

> If you wish to display your graphics for your own use using
>   includegraphic or includegraphics, then comment out the following two
>   lines of code. NB: These line *must* be included when submitting to
>   BMC. All figure files must be submitted as separate graphics through
>   the BMC submission process, not included in the submitted article.

followed by:

```
\def\includegraphic{}
\def\includegraphics{}
```

So, if you want the images to appear in a draft version of your document, you need to comment out those two lines above. I'm guessing (since there's no [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) you haven't done this, which means that `\includegraphics` won't take any arguments, which accounts for the filename appearing, since it's not an argument.

For your final submission-ready paper, you'll have to remove the `graphicx` package, and *possibly* just mark where the images should appear with `\includegraphic` or `\includegraphics` without any arguments or completely remove `\includegraphics`. (This is just guesswork based on a cursory glance at the template, so I recommend you read the author guidelines to check this.)

The template has an example of a couple of figures:

```
  \begin{figure}[h!]
  \caption{\csentence{Sample figure title.}
      A short description of the figure content
      should go here.}
      \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \caption{\csentence{Sample figure title.}
      Figure legend text.}
      \end{figure}
```

These simply have the caption (including their custom `\csentence`, which you don't seem to have used) so I think it's best to just replicate that.

Comment: Thank you, Nicola. I see that I was trying to make the .cls file do something the journal doesn't want me to do. I appreciate your help!